# Inverse Relationship lookups in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

How can I do the following query in Eloquent?

```
SELECT count(*) as total, age
FROM user
JOIN role ON user.role_id = role.id
WHERE role.name = 'maintenance'
GROUP BY age
```

*(where 'age' is on user)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
$total = App\User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'maintenance');
})->groupBy('age')->count();
```